# как подключить css к wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, шаблоны

Здравствуйте.
Укажите на ошибку, помогите подключить css файл к моему шаблону для WP.

header.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
 <title><?php wp_title('«', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
 <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
```

function.php

```html
<?php

function enqueue_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'main_style', get_stylesheet_uri().'/style.css');

}

?>
```

Comment: Как вы вызываете enqueue_styles()?

Comment: пробовал таким образом: add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles'); в function.php   я только учусь, не судите строго)

Comment: В полученной html странице строки `main_style` нету? (может дректорией ошибаетесь). Проверьте, вызывается-ли `enqueue_styles()` (например можете добавить в тело функции `error_log('call enqueue_styles()');` и потом поискать этот текст в логах)

Comment: ... и переименуйте `function.php` в `functions.php`. Скорее всего именно в этом проблема. Если так, удаляйте вопрос

Comment: Спасибо проблема была в имени файла((((